# Why was the term electromotive "force" used instead of voltage or potential difference in original Faraday's law?

Tags: electromagnetism, history

Faraday's law is always given as:

[image: epsilon = -N * ((delta phi_B) / (delta t))]'

I always wondered why a phenomenon which is totally "electrical" and electromagnetic has anything to do with a terminology from mechanics like "force".
If there were anything like an electrical machine like an AC motor the term torque makes very sense.

But what could be the reason historically Faraday himself gave this name "force" on the left side of the equation  instead of using the term "voltage"? In this law there is no force like in the Biot-Savart law, etc.

Comment: This question is easily googlable. https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-electromotive-force-and-potential-difference https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/what-is-the-difference-between-emf-and-voltage.328534/

Comment: On 'force' being found in electrical and electromagnetics; ultimately all measurements must resolve to the three fundamental measurements of mass, length and time. The ampere (SI base electrical unit) is currently (2018) defined as a force between two wires at a specific distance. This can be easily resolved to mass, length and time.

Comment: Related: [Lines of Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_of_force).

Comment: Short version: Faraday thought that "all of reality is made up of force itself".

Comment: It's worth adding that ([according to Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(physics)#Field_theory)) the term *field* in relation to electromagnetics was only introduced in 1849, by Faraday.

Comment: What did he use for the unit of capacitance?

Comment: @PeterSmith I think you mean volt, not ampere.  Also, volt is a derived unit not a base unit.  The ampere is a base unit, however, it does not match the rest of your definition.

Comment: @Transistor microselfs? microselves?  I don't know, but I hear when he abbreviated it he used an 'm' instead of a 'µ', infuriating everybody.  He thought it wasn't a problem because there would 'never be a millime'.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is the term electromotive “force” was used instead of voltage or
>   potential difference in original Faraday's law?

[Volt Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volt): -

> In **1881**, the International Electrical Congress, now the International
>   Electrotechnical Commission (IEC), approved the volt as the unit for
>   electromotive force.

Michael Faraday discovered electromagnetic induction in 1831.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question, why is "electromotive force" named a "force"?

Comment: @ThePhoton Brings to mind an undergrad experiment where voltage is applied between two plates, and attractive force is measured. Relates permittivity of free space and voltage and mechanical force.

Comment: Faraday measured the forces of between conductors with an applied voltage when the conductors were brought close together and C.F.Thomson refined those measurements and found the force between electrodes creates a pressure before arcing about 1% of 1 atmosphere measured in gm/cm^2 at 1mm gap This force resulted in onset of ion flow before an arc where conductor electrons easily escaped the Fermi level.  So it was useful for calculations at the electron level which is less relevant than the macro circuit level. So one reminds themself to use the term EMF when force is a factor as in insulators.